# Is it safe to enable the IR flag in the current version of Solidity?

Tags: solidity, yul

When the IR flag is enabled, it generates a different bytecode from the old compiler since it's using the YUL optimizer.
It's still in active development. So is it safe to enable? Or not yet?

Any further resources or links for more information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The decision to enable the `IR flag` in the Solidity compiler depends on the specific context of your project and your risk tolerance. While the IR flag may generate more optimized `bytecode`, it is still under active development and may contain bugs or issues that could affect the correctness of your contracts.

But here are a few tips to follow if you do enable `IR flag`

1. You should keep up to date with any developments or changes to the `IR optimizer` and adjust your code as needed.
2. Thoroughly test your contracts and ensure that they function correctly after enabling the `IR flag`

Comment: Thx. I would like to know if it might encounter bugs. Solidity's latest official release doesn't contain any warnings to use it. Is there a resource that is risky these days?